# post in javascript for like/dislike system php

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I'm trying to make a like/dislike system for a video where a user can only vote once. I recently implemented Ajax into my code after some research on the web(I have limited knowledge about Ajax). When I click the like or dislike the page refreshes, but it doesn't change anything in the likes/dislikes column in mySQL. Below is the code for the uploaded video.

```
<?php
session_start();
include "config.php";

if( !empty( $_GET['$v_id'] ) ){

    $vid = $_SESSION['v_id'] = $_GET['$v_id'];

 $sql='SELECT video_name FROM video WHERE v_id=?';
    $stmt=$link->prepare( $sql );
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $vid );
    $res=$stmt->execute();
    if( $res ){
        $stmt->store_result();
        $stmt->bind_result( $videoname );
        $stmt->fetch();

        printf('
            <video width="70%%" height="70%%" style="background-color:#585858; border: 4px solid darkorange; border-radius:20px;" controls>
                <source src="uploads/%s" type="video/mp4" id="vid">
            </video>
        ', $videoname );
    }
} else {
    exit('missing ID');
}
```

Below is the code I'm having issues with.

```
<br>
<script>
function postAjax(url, data, success) {
    var params = typeof data == 'string' ? data : Object.keys(data).map(
            function(k){ return encodeURIComponent(k) + '=' + encodeURIComponent(data[k]) }
        ).join('&');

    var xhr = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open('POST', url);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhr.readyState>3 && xhr.status==200) { success(xhr.responseText); }
    };
    xhr.setRequestHeader('X-Requested-With', 'XMLHttpRequest');
    xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');
    xhr.send(params);
    return xhr;
}
</script>

<a href="" onclick="postAjax('localhost/VarcFiles/watchScreen.php?$v_id=\'$vid\'', 'vote=1', function(data){ console.log(data); });"><img src="imageStoring/like.png" style="height:30px;"/></a>
<a href="" onclick="postAjax('localhost/VarcFiles/watchScreen.php?$v_id=\'$vid\'', 'vote=-1', function(data){ console.log(data); });"><img src="imageStoring/dislike.png" style="height:30px;"/></a>
```

Below is the mySQL

```
CREATE TABLE video(
v_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
video_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NULL,
id INT NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY user_id(id)
REFERENCES users(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE,
n_views INT,
likes INT,
dislikes INT,
image_name VARCHAR(225) NOT NILL
);
```

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using [parameterized queries](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add any data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you have created a severe [SQL injection bug](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST`, `$_GET` or data *of any kind* directly into a query, it can be very harmful if someone seeks to exploit your mistake.

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you don't have any code for the actual UPDATE operation.

The SQL should look something like "UPDATE video SET likes = likes+1 WHERE v_id = ?".

Comment: I'm not sure if that would go in "xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {}" or underneath "return xhr;".

Comment: it doesn't go into your javascript. All your xhr does is send a POST request to localhost/VarcFiles/watchScreen.php?v_id=&vid&vote=1.

You have to do the update logic in watchScreen.php, similarly to your code that selects a video to watch.

Comment: I added this "if(xhr){
mysqli_query($link, "UPDATE video SET likes = likes + 1 
                WHERE (v_id = '$vid')");
}" It does like now, however there is no limit. I need it so that a user can only like it once.

Comment: You can make a new table `VideosLikedBy` with a `v_id` and a `user_id`. When you do the like, first check if this video is already liked by this user `SELECT COUNT(*) as count FROM VideosLikedBy WHERE v_id = $vid AND user_id = $user`. If count is greater than 0 then the user has already liked, and you should not increment the likes in the videos table.
Otherwise, you increment the likes but you also need to insert the new row in `VideosLikedBy`

Comment: Sorry for asking late, but I started noticing that its liking when the user enters the page not when they click on the like/dislike button.